# Redirect 301 htaccess whole directory with query to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried to redirect the whole directory to go to the root domain, but I can't get rid off the query

I am trying to redirect `/product-category/featured/?orderby=date` to `root`

I have placed

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301] and 
RewriteRule ^featured/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but the link now goes to mydomain/?orderby=date
how can I get rid of ?orderby=date

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `?`, otherwise the query string is always appended.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301] and 
RewriteRule ^featured/(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have asked earlier and not waste one hour searching the Internet.
Much gratitude!